# Asterisk 1.8 dial multiple number at the same time for outdound conference

Tags: asterisk, conference

i want to connect to 5 numbers at a time to put them in conference call.
i was trying with this dialplan
exten => 123,1,Dial(Dahdi/g0/no_1&Dahdi/g0/no_2&Dahdi/g0/no_3)
with this code who ever answer the call first it will be connected and remaining will get disconnect.

regards
Vikas

Comment: stackoverflow is a programming Q/A site, so this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

That dialplan have be working if you group0 setuped correctly and have enough free channels

You also can use dial Local/123@context/n - call via dialplan